# Node didn't find available persistent volumes to bind

Tags: kubernetes

I am getting error of

> 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.

upon creating my pod to attach to Persistent Storage.

I have setup below.

`PersistentVolume` and `StorageClass` created and attached successfully.
Once I create PersistentVolumeClaim, it waits in "pending" state, which is expected (I believe) because 
it waits a pod to connect due to "`WaitForFirstConsumer`" setting of `StorageClass`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-local-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /home/aozdemir/k8s
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - my-node
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-local-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: example-local-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

My problem is that, after I create the Pod, it gives following warning:

> 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent
>   volumes to bind.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: In case if someone gets stuck with the same problem on a multi-node cluster having one master and one worker node, I resolved it by providing the name of worker-node in the 'values' field for the 'key: kubernetes.io/hostname'.

Answer (score 18):

It was my bad.
Due to following blog post: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/

> Note that there’s a new **nodeAffinity** field in the PersistentVolume
>   object: this is how the Kubernetes scheduler understands that this
>   PersistentVolume is tied to a specific node. nodeAffinity is a
>   **required field for local PersistentVolumes**.

and my value was incorrect. I changed it to my node name, and re-deployed, it worked.

Comment: Can you post the updated yaml for reference?