# JupyterHub Hub Pod stuck in pending - pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, jupyterhub, flannel

I am having issues deploying juypterhub on kubernetes cluster. The issue I am getting is that the hub pod is stuck in pending.

Stack:
kubeadm
flannel
weave
helm
jupyterhub

Runbook:

```
$kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr="10.244.0.0/16" 
$sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/ && sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf && export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
$kubectl create -f pvc.yml
$kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel-aliyun.yml
$kubectl apply --filename https://git.io/weave-kube-1.6
$kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Helm installations as per https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-helm.html

Jupyter installations as per https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-jupyterhub.html

**config.yml**

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "asdf"
singleuser:
  storage:
    dynamic:
      storageClass: local-storage
```

**pvc.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: standard
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  # volumeMode field requires BlockVolume Alpha feature gate to be enabled.
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /dev/vdb
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - example-node
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: standard
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

The warning is:

```
$kubectl --namespace=jhub get pod

NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hub-fb48dfc4f-mqf4c      0/1     Pending   0          3m33s
proxy-86977cf9f7-fqf8d   1/1     Running   0          3m33s

$kubectl --namespace=jhub describe pod hub

Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  35s (x3 over 35s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims



$kubectl --namespace=jhub describe pv

Name:            standard
Labels:          type=local
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    manual
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/standard
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        10Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /dev/vdb
    HostPathType:
Events:            <none>


$kubectl --namespace=kube-system describe pvc

Name:          hub-db-dir
Namespace:     jhub
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app=jupyterhub
               chart=jupyterhub-0.8.0-beta.1
               component=hub
               heritage=Tiller
               release=jhub
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Events:
  Type       Reason         Age                From                         Message
  ----       ------         ----               ----                         -------
  Normal     FailedBinding  13s (x7 over 85s)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
Mounted By:  hub-fb48dfc4f-mqf4c
```

I tried my best to follow the localstorage volume configuration on the official kubernetes website, but with no luck

-G

Comment: Hi how come  status of the PV is bound ? `Status:  Bound`

Comment: @Suresh I have re-run it and it is giving me Status: Available but I still have the same issue

Comment: Hi, it is looking for the storageclass to create a dynamic volume for the PVC. Can you run the following command ? `kubectl get storageclass` , I will cross check how it work with localvolume

Comment: Hi Suresh
`# kubectl --namespace jhub get storageclass
NAME            PROVISIONER                    AGE
local-storage   kubernetes.io/no-provisioner   4m26s`

`# kubectl --namespace jhub describe storageclass
Name:                  local-storage
IsDefaultClass:        No
Annotations:           <none>
Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
Parameters:            <none>
AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     WaitForFirstConsumer
Events:                <none>`

Comment: Hi, lets make this Storage class default , here is the reference and check out the step 3 https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/

Comment: I want to make it default due to this message from your pvc ` no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
Mounted By:  hub-fb48dfc4f-mqf4c`

Comment: Hi,
Now I have a different issue
`# kubectl --namespace=jhub describe pods hub-5cf796f878-cnwvt`
gives
`Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  21s (x9 over 5m22s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.`

I followed this but still no luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964239/node-didnt-find-available-persistent-volumes-to-bind

Comment: Hi, can you run the following command 
`kubectl get nodes --show-labels` and ` kubectl descrive pods $POD_NAME`

Comment: `root@iZp0w8theu5ou7qgsgn3boZ:~# kubectl --namespace=jhub get nodes --show-labels
NAME                      STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   LABELS
izp0w8theu5ou7qgsgn3boz   Ready    master   24h   v1.13.3   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=izp0w8theu5ou7qgsgn3boz,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=`

Comment: `kubectl --namespace=jhub describe pod hub`
https://pastebin.com/Rc18LM2z

Comment: Hi  @gpaw. it seems that there is something wrong with your node `  0/1 nodes are available`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188678/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-gpaw).

Comment: HI, sorry, Somehow I did not get the notification from the chat, glad it worked, Its quite strange we did not see the cause its related to affinities

Answer (score 6):

Managed to fix it using the following configuration.
Key points:
 - I forgot to add the node in nodeAffinity
 - it works without putting in volumeBindingMode

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: standard
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  # volumeMode field requires BlockVolume Alpha feature gate to be enabled.
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /temp
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - INSERT_NODE_NAME_HERE
```

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
```

config.yaml

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "token"
singleuser:
  storage:
    dynamic:
      storageClass: local-storage
```

make sure your storage/pv looks like this:

```
root@asdf:~# kubectl --namespace=kube-system describe pv
Name:              standard
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolume","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"standard"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"capa...
                   pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:      local-storage
Status:            Bound
Claim:             jhub/hub-db-dir
Reclaim Policy:    Retain
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          2Gi
Node Affinity:
  Required Terms:
    Term 0:        kubernetes.io/hostname in [asdf]
Message:
Source:
    Type:  LocalVolume (a persistent volume backed by local storage on a node)
    Path:  /temp
Events:    <none>
```

```
root@asdf:~# kubectl --namespace=kube-system describe storageclass
Name:                  local-storage
IsDefaultClass:        Yes
Annotations:           storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=true
Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
Parameters:            <none>
AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     Immediate
Events:                <none>
```

Now the hub pod looks something like this:

```
root@asdf:~# kubectl --namespace=jhub describe pod hub
Name:               hub-5d4fcd8fd9-p6crs
Namespace:          jhub
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               asdf/192.168.0.87
Start Time:         Sat, 23 Feb 2019 14:29:51 +0800
Labels:             app=jupyterhub
                    component=hub
                    hub.jupyter.org/network-access-proxy-api=true
                    hub.jupyter.org/network-access-proxy-http=true
                    hub.jupyter.org/network-access-singleuser=true
                    pod-template-hash=5d4fcd8fd9
                    release=jhub
Annotations:        checksum/config-map: --omitted
                    checksum/secret: --omitted--
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.244.0.55
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/hub-5d4fcd8fd9
Containers:
  hub:
    Container ID:  docker://d2d4dec8cc16fe21589e67f1c0c6c6114b59b01c67a9f06391830a1ea711879d
    Image:         jupyterhub/k8s-hub:0.8.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://jupyterhub/k8s-hub@sha256:e40cfda4f305af1a2fdf759cd0dcda834944bef0095c8b5ecb7734d19f58b512
    Port:          8081/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      jupyterhub
      --config
      /srv/jupyterhub_config.py
      --upgrade-db
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 23 Feb 2019 14:30:28 +0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:     200m
      memory:  512Mi
    Environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED:        1
      HELM_RELEASE_NAME:       jhub
      POD_NAMESPACE:           jhub (v1:metadata.namespace)
      CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN:  <set to the key 'proxy.token' in secret 'hub-secret'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /etc/jupyterhub/config/ from config (rw)
      /etc/jupyterhub/secret/ from secret (rw)
      /srv/jupyterhub from hub-db-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from hub-token-bxzl7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      hub-config
    Optional:  false
  secret:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  hub-secret
    Optional:    false
  hub-db-dir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  hub-db-dir
    ReadOnly:   false
  hub-token-bxzl7:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  hub-token-bxzl7
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```